# Diurnal cycle of data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby, pandas-resample

I have data recorded automatically every minute.
The data looks like this

[image]

The plot that I am trying to have should be like this.

[image]

I am trying to average each variable such that the final will have 1440 (60X24) time steps. In this way, I will able to plot the diurnal cycle of each variable.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
xdata = pd.read_csv("station_2019_2.csv")

xtime = pd.date_range("2019-10-01", "2019-11-01", freq="min")

ydata = xdata.drop(columns=["Date", "Time"])


df = pd.DataFrame(ydata)


df["Date"] = xtime[1:]

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

mHI  = df.resample('1Min')['Hi'].mean()

print(np.shape(mHI))
```

Unfortunately, is not working.
Any help will be appreciated.

regards

Answer (score 0):

When you read the csv file into a dataframe, pandas generates a default index consisting of consecutive integers. That's why your code

```py
df["Date"] = xtime[1:]
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

isn't working. Pandas doesn't know how to convert the integer index to the datetime format. Instead, you could do this:

```py
df.index = xtime[1:]
```

However, if I understand you correctly, no resampling is necessary, because you already have minutely frequency. So you may not even need the datetime index.

To average the values for each minute over several days, do not drop the time column, so that you can do this:

```py
df_average_day = df.groupby('Time').mean()
```

Comment: Hi Arne, At the final, 
I want to produce a file that will do average, for each day, the same time frame. 


For example, do an average of all 00:01, 00:02, .... 

The final file will be the mean day

Comment: Ah, I see. I have edited the answer. Please let me know if this works.

Comment: As Arne,

As you can see in my script "Time" column was dropped. 

So, for your final suggestion, there is no more column which is called Time

New index created is "no name column"

Comment: I know, that's why I said "do not drop the time column".

Comment: You may not even need the datetime index.

Comment: Is working without dropping the time. 

thank you for your kind help